# where to store boolean value to be accessed by child fragments on Android app

Tags: android

I was wondering where I would store a boolean value which would be set in a Main activity that has a drawer layout to be accessed by child fragments/components.  Perhaps later down the road, I may think of persisting it in a database, but I don't think I need one at the moment for this single boolean.  Would I keep it in an intent? Thank you!

Comment: sharedpreferences ?

Comment: SharedPreferences , Preferences DataStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- sharedpreferences
- set in the activity itself and access it from fragment using getter.
- Pass it in a bundle as an argument to the fragment